# JS - Filter Data - Using Push & Splice

Tags: javascript, checkbox

If I have 3 sets of checkboxes (each set contains N number of checkboxes), and the checkboxes are pulling from the same data set, how do I incorporate an "AND" functionality so that if you select an item or 2 from the 1st set of checkboxes and then select a checkbox or 2 from the 2nd set of checkboxes, only the items that match are displayed...essentially each checkbox (per set of checkboxes) is a filter? Similar to the functionality here: http://jsfiddle.net/jessica_b/7uGDX/

```
var disar = new Array();

function cboxFilet(actionAdd, idList) {

    if (actionAdd == true) {

        for (var r in idList) {
            disar.push(idList[r]);
        }
        alert("ADD: " + disar);
    } else {

        for (r in idList) {
            var loc = disar.indexOf(idList[r]);
            disar.splice(loc, 1);
        }
        alert("REMOVE: " + disar);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method would solve this problem for you. Here's a rough example below:

```
var properties = { //this object will have to be changed when the user selects different checkboxes
    filter1: <>,
    filter2: <>,
    ...
    filterN: <>
};

var disar = objArray.filter(function(elem){ 
        for(property in properties){
            if(!item[property]){ return false; }
        }
        return true;
    });
```

please note that this only checks for the presence of each filter in the array of objects, and you can easily change it so that it checks for specific rules. (eg 'age' > 30)

Comment: I think I am doing it wrong. I am always getting true. Here is what I have:
   https://codeshare.io/tZSm9

Comment: Almost. I have attached an image of what the UI looks like [here](http://i.imgur.com/Bd9GPdw.png). In the pic there are 3 sections for checkboxes, if you select something from section 1, then you selection something from section 2; values that section 1 & 2 have in common. The same for section 3. How can I do that? Thanks a bunch!!!